# how to append arraylist and display in listview in android

Tags: android

I am getting the value from webservice  first 50 record display in list view .I have load button in footer. if user click load button i will get next 50 record from webservice .how to append first 50 and second 50..n and show it in list view  can anybody tell how to do

**I am using arraylist of data object**

Thanks

Comment: If you are using custom adapter, then in your getCount() of adapter just return i+50; and initialize i=50; and call notifyDataSetChanged() on button footer. It will load next 50 to list. Then no need to merge two arraylist,

Comment: please give some source code @user370305

Comment: @Cristiana214 - For what question? What is your problem? Describe properly.

Comment: thanks but i already got it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get other 50 records in another temp arraylist and append these with your original Arraylist by calling addAll() method of your original arraylist then after again rebind your listView with adapter having  your mearged arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

You just add the new 50 records in to the arraylist which you have passed to the adapter of the list and call adapters notifydatasetchanged method to refresh the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about ArrayList merging then You can merge them by using `addAll()` method of List.

Answer (score 0):

ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById( R.id.myListView );
final ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();
final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems );
listView.setAdapter( adapter );

Hope it help you!!